# Structures in C# in the Form Class to access from different methods

Tags: c#

I am using a structure to put there similar variables I am using afterwards in a function. I need to access these variables from methods in the form, that is why I am doing it like that...  I am using collections because I need to calculate some statistics with the data.

My question is: is it a good practice to do it like this? or you can suggest me a better way to deal with this?

Thanks for your help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private struct Values
        {
            static public Collection<double> temp = new Collection<double>();
            static public Collection<DateTime> time = new Collection<DateTime>(); 
        }

        private void Method()
        {
            Values.temp = ...
            Values.time = ...
        }

        private void Method2()
        {
            Values.temp = ...
            Values.time = ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: Global variables are the `goto` of data declarations.  At least wrap them with a property so you can set a breakpoint on the setter.  You'll need it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I wanted to do something else. How do you suggest me to wrap them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting `static` fields and `struct`s very badly. **Don't do this.** Why?

1. The semantics of `struct`s is very different from `class`es. If you are not getting what's wrong with your code, it's highly likely you won't use `struct`s properly and fully understand their value semantics.
2. Your `temp` and `time` fields are `static` which means their values will be shared *among all instances* of your `Form1`. This is generally wrong, unless you really know what you are doing.

Don't experiment with unusual, strange, and unreadable constructs. Resort to plain old working practices:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Collection<double> temp = new Collection<double>();
    public Collection<DateTime> time = new Collection<DateTime>(); 
    …
}
```

There's hardly any valid reason for the `Values.Xyz` construct you are trying to introduce.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to avoid using public variables, accessible from outside the Form class as you are proposing here. That is why I wanted them to include inside a structure... but I could use the same you say but private instead of public. I think it is better...

Comment: There's absolutely no reason not to use `private` in that case. You should read some C# book to better understand the very basics.

Comment: I perfectly understand that the variables can be defined as private. That is how I am using them now. What you proposed is using them as public. I just wanted to find a way to have them encapsulated so they are not available for the whole class...

Comment: You should understand that what you did was absolutely misleading at the first place. Being `public` or `private` is **JUST** a matter of one keyword. Being `static` versus *instance* members is **the key point here**.